# Cannot read property 'geocodeAddress' of undefined

Tags: react-native

Any one may help me with this error in **react-native-geocode**.

```js
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    this.searchEvents('hackathon', 'London');
  },

  searchEvents(category, city) {
    Geocoder.geocodeAddress('London').then(response => {
      console.log('response', response);
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Did you follow all the [**installation steps**](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder#install)?

Comment: The error is in the geocodeAddress(), it's undefined and i tried also geocodeLocation and i faced the same problem despite i followed the installation steps and it installed fine @AnamulHasan

Comment: `Cannot read property 'geocodeAddress' of undefined` - that means `Geocoder` is undefined. not even reach `geocodeAddress()` yet.

Comment: So what's the solution you suggest ? @Val

Comment: @WaelAl-ameen Check if `react-native-geocoder` exists in `node_modules`. reinstall and try again.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled it so many times, cleaned the cache, and the result is the same @Val